# Prove that $13|2^{70}+3^{70}$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

> Prove that $$13|2^{70}+3^{70}$$

Any HINT how I can start solving this task? What can be a first step?

Comment: Well, I have attempted to transform the "right side", but I have no idea how to do it

Comment: Ok, indeed there was such a question. Should I remove my question or not?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Recall that $(a+b) \vert (a^{2n+1} + b^{2n+1})$ where $n \in \mathbb{N}$ (Why?) and note that we have
$$2^{70} + 3^{70} = (2^2)^{35} + (3^2)^{35} = 4^{35} + 9^{35}$$

Comment: +1 Thanks a lot! I will try to finish this task with your hint. It seems to be very helpful!